# Засчитывается ли upvote тревоги?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Возможно, подобный вопрос уже был отвечен на мете, но я толком даже и не знаю, по каким словам искать. По крайней мере просмотрел все вопросы с тегом [тревоги](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8).

Суть вопроса очень проста. Иногда бывает открываешь вопрос - а внутри уже красуется комментарий вида:

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из
>   функции обратного
>   вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)
>   – Grundy 14 минут назад

Я бывает просмотрев ссылку хочу согласиться с тем, что да, это дубликат и беру ставлю upvote комментарию. Мол, да, очень похоже на дубликат и я согласен с этим. Ну и горела цифра "три" у этого комментария, а стала "четыре".

И вот недавно я вдруг увидел, что на странице где перечислены мои тревоги я не нахожу комментариев, которые я "апнул" -- только те тревоги, где я сам первый указывал на дубликат.

Итого, я могу точно сказать, что эти действия не записываются в личную статистику. Но также я подозреваю, что они не влияют и на реальное количество голосов тех, кто согласен с дубликатом.

И есть ли вообще смысл добавлять плюсик к тревоге или всё равно потом будут учитываться не эти плюсики, а голосование в очереди проверок?

Чуть более другой вопрос: а если уже кто-то отметил сообщение как дубликат и ты хочешь указать точно такую же ссылку как дубликат -- насколько это полезно/бесполезно.

Comment: был где-то похожий вопрос про то что на комментарии плюсов была куча, а вопрос все еще не закрыт

Comment: @Grundy, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2621/178988

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upvote тревоги не засчитывается и к закрытию вопроса не приводит.

Это не плюсик на тревоге, а просто голос за комментарий, который автоматически добавляется при закрытии как дубликат.

Надо именно голосовать за закрытие, с указанием той же ссылки.

Comment: В целом ответ понятен, подозревал что-то подобное. Уточните формулировку: "надо именно голосовать за закрытие" -- под этим подразумевается "вы должны ещё раз подать тревогу с таким же id вопроса" или "вы должны в очереди проверок голосовать за закрытие" (у меня есть ссылка на "очереди проверок", но что внутри "голоса за закрытие я только догадываюсь). По смыслу похоже, что именно "подать такую же тревогу". Непонятно также, будет ли как-то учитываться дубликат тревоги в голосовании на закрытии? Или они видятся там как разные тревоги и лишь зря увеличивают энтропию проверяющих?

Comment: @AK для пользователей с репутацией > 3000 тревоги за закрытие превращаются в голоса. При наборе 5 голосов за закрытие - вопрос закрывается. Для вопросов, на которых висят тревоги / голоса за закрытие, есть отдельная очередь, доступная от тех же 3000.

Comment: @AK т.е. до набора 3к на вопросы, за закрытие которых уже кто-то проголосовал, вы особо повлиять не можете. Можете оставить еще одну тревогу - но она тоже ни на что не повлияет (т.к. это не полноценный голос). Механизим достаточно подробно расписан в справке: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: А вообще удобно было бы апнув комментарий было эквивалентно "скопировал ссылку  - нажал тревога - подставил ссылку - нажал отправить". Меньше действий требуется.

Comment: @AK если на вопросе уже висит тревога или голос закрытия как дубликат - то ссылка на него автоматом подставляется в диалоге закрытия. т.е. копировать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Вот не обращал внимания на такую мелочь. Может и правда подставляется. Сколько полезного узнал )) Спасибо за ответы и комментарии.

Comment: _"Можете оставить еще одну тревогу - но она тоже ни на что не повлияет"_ - повлияет на количество полезных тревог в профиле и прогресс соответствующих значков же?